# Turtle Module Error

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

new to python here. I am trying to learn about the turtle module in python but I am having trouble setting it up. This is the script i am trying to run:

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()

print(bob)
turtle.mainloop()
bob.fd(1000)
```

and this is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "turtle_test.py", line 6, in <module>
    bob.fd(1000)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 1637, in forward
    self._go(distance)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 1605, in _go
    self._goto(ende)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 3158, in _goto
    screen._pointlist(self.currentLineItem),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 755, in _pointlist
    cl = self.cv.coords(item)
  File "<string>", line 1, in coords
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2466, in coords
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args))]
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
```

If any could help me and point out what i am doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have the lines in the wrong order:

```
import turtle

bob = turtle.Turtle()
print(bob)
bob.fd(1000)

turtle.mainloop()
```

The final `turtle.mainloop()` line turns control over to tkinter's event loop so any lines after that won't get executed until the window is closed and the turtle environment has been torn down.  I.e. it's usually the last thing you do in a turtle program.